# Special Formatting for WordPress Plugin Description?

Tags: plugin-development, formatting

Last question,
I am supplying the Description of my plugin [see the part of this called "Customizing the Plugin Information Box"](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-automatic-plugin-updates/), and I can't get any HTML format to work. It just prints off like normal text. Wondering how to get formatting in this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following markup in a plugin description:

- `a[href][title]`,
- `abbr[title]`,
- `acronym[title]`,
- `code`,
- `em`,
- `strong`

Anything else will be rendered as plain text (escaped).